# Issue with multi-language settings in game

Tags: c++, windows, multilingual

I've added the ability to select several languages in this game, but I'm having some issue with it. The main issue is if one player has the english language selected, and another has japanese selected, the japanese player can read the english languages, but the english player can't read their language. On game-launch, the selected language is read from an xml called config.xml (it gets the childcontents of code), then from there depending on which language is selected, goes to the folder and loads in the language xmls. Is there a way to like, embed or load all languages at the same time so players can read korean/japanese text and not a bunch of question marks?

the code :

```
void ZLanguageSetting_formultilanguage::SetLanguageIndexFromCmdLineStr(const char* cmdline)
{
const unsigned int id_USA = 0;
const unsigned int id_DUT = 1;
const unsigned int id_SPA = 2;
const unsigned int id_POR = 3;
const unsigned int id_GER = 4;
const unsigned int id_KOR = 5;
const unsigned int id_JAP = 6;

m_idLang = id_USA;

if (NULL == cmdline) return;

if      (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=en")) m_idLang = id_USA;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=du")) m_idLang = id_DUT;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=sp")) m_idLang = id_SPA;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=po")) m_idLang = id_POR;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=ge")) m_idLang = id_GER;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=ko")) m_idLang = id_POR;
else if (NULL!= strstr(cmdline, "&u100e:2=ja")) m_idLang = id_GER;
}

ZLanguageSetting_formultilanguage g_LanguageSettingformultilanguage;
ZLanguageSetting_formultilanguage* ZGetLanguageSetting_formultilanguage()
                                    { return &g_LanguageSettingformultilanguage; }

const char* ZConfiguration::GetLanguagePath()
{
    switch (GetSelectedLanguageIndex())
    {
     case 1:
        return PATH_DUT;
     case 2:
        return PATH_SPA;
     case 3:
        return PATH_POR;
     case 4:
        return PATH_GER;
     case 5:
        return PATH_KOR;
     case 6:
        return PATH_JAP;
     case 7:
        return PATH_USA;
     default:
        return PATH_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

This is the base of the code that selects from the cmdline and then loads one of these paths containing the xmls into memory. Hope this thread has all of the necessary information, if not I'll update as needed. Thanks

Comment: I see you missed out English in that list :-(

Comment: It's listed under id_usa, but it should be id_eng, i'll change that later in case someone else works on my project with me. Hah just saw a error with my code, accidentally added id_ger twice && id_por twice

Comment: One wonders what happened to the English language on that boat. What you yanks use is a dialect of English.

Comment: I'm very aware of this lol, it's easily changed to say id_eng, PATH_ENG :p

Comment: I do not understand the part about question marks. Question marks appear when someone is trying to display characters that are not supported by font and/or current codepage. Using a decent Unicode font and using Unicode in interface (that is, WinAPI functions with suffix W) should be enough to let everyone see their native language at the same time.

Comment: It's confusing to me as well. If I or another player changes their system locale to korean, then the korean and japanese language becomes readable, if they don't, it stays as question marks. This is how the xml header is set up:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Maybe japanese/korean dont support utf-8?

Comment: I observed this behavior with non-Unicode programs. Unicode programs can display all characters. E.g. your browser (I hope) uses Unicode, so you can see some Korean (향찰/鄕札), Japanese (ひらがな), Cyrillic (АБВГД), and Western European (äçøî) at the same time, regardless of your current locale.

Comment: Ahh I see, well this is quite an older game, so it could lack unicode support.

Comment: In that case, move to UTF-8, and convert manually on calling WINAPI.

Comment: Well, luckily it seems the game already uses UTF-8, so I just need to do the latter. I hate to ask, but what would be an example of converting on calling WINAPI, never messed with winapi.

Comment: Nvm I'm an idiot, I see exactly what I need to do. Gotta switch over to using std::wstring

Comment: Please post the answer and accept it. (I didn't understand the question because I thought both the English and Japanese players were at the same computer.)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is the program is very old, doesn't use Unicode, uses MBCS, would take far too long to convert everything over to Unicode, so I'm removing the japanese and korean languages.